# App stops unexpectedly when using OnTouchListener, MotionEvent.ACTION_UP

Tags: java, android, ontouchlistener, motionevent

So I want to create buttons that play music as long as it is pressed, but once it is released, the music stops.

In my `createListeners()`, I have the following:

```
b1.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                startBeat(1, m1);
                return true;
            } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                m1.stop();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

`m1` is a `MediaPlayer`, and in the method `startBeat`, `m1.start()` has been called.

When running the app, the music plays fine, as long as I don't release the button. However, the moment I release the button, the app says it stopped unexpectedly. What could be causing this problem?

Is there another way I could go about implementing this feature?

Comment: What's the log say when you crash?

Comment: please you have to post your error log, also your `startBeat` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** I found out what I was doing wrong. I was initializing and starting the MediaPlayer in my startBeat method, and stopping the player in the onTouch method. Once I moved it all into onTouch, it worked. So I guess something weird was happening before. Thanks for the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you try play again the [`MediaPlayer`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html) ??

> Calling stop() stops playback and causes a MediaPlayer in the Started, Paused, Prepared or PlaybackCompleted state to enter the Stopped state.
>   Once in the Stopped state, **playback cannot be started until prepare() or prepareAsync() are called to set the MediaPlayer** object to the Prepared state again.

If you don't, try `m1.pause();` and `m1.seekTo(0)` to simulate the stop...

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        startBeat(1, m1);
        return true;
    } else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        m1.pause();
        m1.seekTo(0);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```